# How to search elastic search via Java using ElasticsearchRepository?

Tags: java, spring, rest, elasticsearch

I'm creating a Java application using Elastic Search.
Here is the link for my project.
https://github.com/chanakaDe/ensembl-elastic-rest

In this project, I have implemented a rest controller to take data as JSON.
This is the controller class. Now it only has 2 methods. But I need to add some method like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find-by/{id}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Iterable<Track> findAllWithParams(@PathVariable int id, @PathVariable String param1, @PathVariable String param2, @PathVariable String param3) {
    return trackService.someMethodWithParams(id, param1, param2, param3);
}
```

What I need to do is take some values from user and send them into Elastic server and make a search. I just refered some of these links and got some idea.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

TrackService.java and TrackServiceImpl.java are implemented by TrackRepository.java and it's extended by ElasticsearchRepository default class. https://github.com/chanakaDe/ensembl-elastic-rest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/chanaka/book/repository/TrackRepository.java

I need to take values via REST URL and create an object like following and pass that to Elastic Server. How can I implement that with my current project configuration ?

```
{
"query": {
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { "user" : ["kimchy", "elasticsearch"]}
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is my TrackService.java interface.

```
public interface TrackService {

Track save(Track track);

Track findOne(int id);

Iterable<Track> findAll();
```

}

And also this is my TrackServiceImpl.java class implemented by TrackService.java.

```
public class TrackServiceImpl implements TrackService {

private TrackRepository trackRepository;

@Autowired
public void setTrackRepository(TrackRepository trackRepository) {this.trackRepository = trackRepository;}

@Override
public Track save(Track track) {
    return trackRepository.save(track);
}

@Override
public Track findOne(int id) {
    return trackRepository.findOne(id + "");
}

@Override
public Iterable<Track> findAll() {
    return trackRepository.findAll();
}
```

}

Do I need to implement a custom method for that ? Or is there any default methods like findAll() and findOne() ? 
Simply pass an object and get the value ?

Comment: Guys no one to answer me :(

Answer (score 0):

I think, there's no such existing method and you need to create your own by using `QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(query.toString())` and `ElasticsearchTemplate`. Just to note, `wrapperQuery` supports only query not filter. But you can achieve filter context query with `constant_score`.